# Consider the system: $\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}\dot{x_1}=x_1y-x_1x_2^2 \\ \\ \dot{x_2}=x_2y-x_2x_1^2\\ \\ \dot{y}=-y+x_1^2+x_2^2 \end{array} \right.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Consider the system:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \dot{x_1}=x_1y-x_1x_2^2 \\
             \\ \dot{x_2}=x_2y-x_2x_1^2\\
             \\ \dot{y}=-y+x_1^2+x_2^2 
             \end{array}
   \right.$

Obtain an approximation for the stable and center varieties and make the phase portrait. (Get the orbits on the center variety here)

I know how to calculate the center variety for a system of two equations but I do not know how to do it for three, could someone help me please? When there are two equations one makes $x_2=h(x_1)$ and so $\dot{x_2}=\frac{\partial h(x_1)}{\partial x_1}\dot{x_1}$, then helping each other by Taylor series, one gets explicitly to $h(x_1)$. How do I find the stable variety? I know that the stable variety of the center variety are tangent to the stable space and the center space respectively, but how do I find them in this case? Thank you very much.

Comment: The same, you should write $y=h(x_1,x_2)$ and use the Taylor series in the two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. Also, the same for the stable manifold, $x_1=h_1(y), x_2=h_2(y)$ using the Taylor series in $y$.

Comment: @JohnB I do not know if I've done the following things well: $\dot{y}=h_{x_1}(x_1, x_2)\dot{x_1}+h_{x_2}(x_1, x_2)\dot{x_2}$ so $-y+x_1^2+x_2^2=h_{x_1}(x_1, x_2)(x_1y-x_1x_2^2)+h_{x_2}(x_1, x_2)(-y+x_1^2+x_2^2)$

Comment: All is exactly as you wrote, now you need to make sure that the coefficients of the Taylor series on the two sides agree. You can write down say $h(x_1,x_2)=ax_1^2+bx_1x_2+cx_2^2+\cdots$.

Comment: @JohnB I know that $h(x_1,x_2)=h(0,0)+h_{x_1}(0,0)x_1+h_{x_2}(0,0)x_2+...$ where $h(0,0)=0, h_{x_1}(0,0)=0, h_{x_2}(0,0)=0$ and then what is $h_{x_1}(x_1,x_2)$ and $h_{x_2}(x_1,x_2)$? Is there an easier way to find this? Taylor's expansion in two variables seems very long and complex.

Comment: Those are the derivatives of the whole series. Better as I wrote, with constants $a,b,c$, etc, since it is usually unlikely to be able to obtain the whole Taylor series. So we usually look for the terms up to a certain order. On the other hand, for this particular equation the stable manifold is quite immediate, why?

Comment: @JohnB Why? Because it is tangent to the stable space and is always the $x_1$ axis?

Comment: Right. --------

Comment: @JohnB Why is the $x_1$ axis always?

Comment: It is not. ----